# Make Button always be at corner of the screen?

Tags: unity, gui

How can I make a button always be at the corner of the screen like so:

[image]

Currently I have a button, child of canvas that does this:

[image]

Comment: Are you setting its coordinates relative to the view? Otherwise it will just get left behind as the view changes.

Answer (score 1):

There are terms called *Anchor/Reference/Pivot Points* on which objects are based, means they will draw respective to their anchor points. For example if you set pivot at very left of the button and you command it to draw at (0,0), then button's left part will be at (0,0).

So in your case when you are using Unity UI, there is also an option to set *pivot* point.

[image]

And from there, you can set your pivot. In you case, you have to set your anchor to the top left, as like this,

[image]

Actually it will maintain the distance from top-left of the screen